# Strategy to build efficiently an image using parts of many images

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing, image

I have about 1000 images of 1000px $\times$ 1000px and a list which contains the coordinates of the pixels to select, for each of the 1000 images. Each pixel is used once, so the final image is a full image made of parts of all the other images.

Here is an example code for 2 images:

```
img1 = ImageData[Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]];
img2 = ImageData[ColorNegate[Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]]];
img = img1;
ptsToReplace = RandomInteger[{1, 116}, 10000] // Partition[#, 2] &;
Table[img[[Sequence @@ ptsToReplace[[i]]]] = 
   img2[[Sequence @@ ptsToReplace[[i]]]], {i, 1, 
   Length[ptsToReplace]}];
ImageAssemble[Map[Image, {img1, img2, img}]]
```

Below are the two images and the output on the right which is a mix of them:

[image]

My question is about what strategy to use:

- Loading all the images, then converting all of them as arrays with `ImageData` and then building the final image by iterating on the pixel works, but is of course quickly limited by the memory as it stores everything (images + arrays).
- I also tried to iterate on the images: for each image, get all the pixels that I will need to take, copy them to the final image, and proceed again with next image. This is OK as far as memory is concerned, but it is too slow.
- I thought about more efficient ways such as creating mask images which would have black dots on the coordinates of the pixels which have to be used for a given image, and then multiply the images. The goal being to avoid iteration on pixels and use faster build-in functions. But I don't know how to do this efficiently (e.g. not building the mask by iterating over the pixels).

What would be an efficient technique, in both CPU and memory? I insist that the coordinates to replace (`ptsToReplace` here) are independent of the images, so I really have to use a table (for each image) of table of points as an input.

Answer (score 9):

This produces the same result ( about 5x faster )

```
img1 = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
img2 = ColorNegate[Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]];
ImageAdd[
   ImageMultiply[img1, 
         Image[1 - SparseArray[ ptsToReplace -> 1 ,
              Reverse@ImageDimensions[img2]]]],
   ImageMultiply[img2, 
         Image[SparseArray[ ptsToReplace -> 1 , 
              Reverse@ImageDimensions[img2]]]]]
```

For a bunch of files you might do something like this:

```
dim=Reverse@ImageDimensions@Import@files[[1]];
 (*assumes all images are the same size*)
Fold[ImageAdd[#1,
     ImageMultiply[
        Import[files[[#2]]], 
        Image@SparseArray[ ptsToReplace[[#2]] -> 1 , dim]
                  ]
             ] &,  
          Image@SparseArray[{1, 1} -> 0, dim] , Range@Length@files ]
```

where `files` is a list of file names and `ptsToReplace` is a list of the points to keep for each file.

Comment: I tested the second code as well and: i) it works fine (you can edit your answer to remove _untested_) ii) i solves the memory problem iii) it is still not very fast; of course I loaded 500 images of 1Mo so I guess it has to take some time, but would you see any possible strategy to gain more speed? Thank you anyway!

Comment: `Fold` is only loading one file at a time, so memory should not be an issue. My guess the file i/o is the main bottleneck. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: I just "translated" the program into Python, with basically the same algorithm as the one you propose. I am surprised by how much faster it goes (about 6 times). My guess is that it is because I used "packed" low-level (in C) commands of numpy, while mathematica is at a much higher level.