# How fast can I split an image?

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

Consider an image(`img`) as

[image]

I have defined two functions for splitting and displaying as follows:

```
splitImage[img_, n_] := Module[{w, h, parts},
   {w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
   parts = ImagePartition[img, {w/n, h/n}]
   ];

showParts[parts_] := Module[{},
   ImageAssemble[parts /. i_Image :> ImagePad[i, 1, 1]]
   ];
```

Now,

```
showParts[splitImage[img, 64]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

gives me the timing as

> 4.61676

I need to split the image into `64x64` blocks and I want to speed up the process as much as possible.

How can I optimize the speed?

**Edit 1** Here is the performance comparison of all the four techniques (executed on my machine):

> @CoolWater: 0.0707495
>
> @AnjanKumar: 0.510273
>
> @Majis: 6.95316
>
> @Alucard: 12.5303

**Edit 2: Performance comparison updated for splitting**

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Now I need you to recommend me which technique I should follow to access each individual part after splitting so that the combined speed will be the fastest.

[I can do the comparison myself but not all the techniques give me a direct access to the individual parts.]

Comment: why not `Grid@ImagePartition[img, 64]` ? This does the same and it is about 1000x faster in my old Intel I3. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas I need `64x64` blocks (which in this case will be of the size `4x4`) and not blocks of size `64x64.`

Comment: I obtain a time 150x faster for a showing blocks of 4x4 for an image of  512x512, using what I proposed above

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas May be. But on my machine, it can't even compute for `4x4` blocks.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Yes, you are right. It's more than 150 times faster. But I also need a similar display what I can get using `showParts`. Using `Grid` the spacing is very large.

Comment: You can control the `Spacings` to get a more compact display

Comment: Related: [94478](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94478/strategy-to-build-efficiently-an-image-using-parts-of-many-images)

Comment: @Majis can you check  the second solution i added on your machine please?

Comment: Do you only really need the padded image? Your splitting method should be more than fast enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that is a magnitude faster than the fastest method so far when it comes to rendering the image:

```
showParts[img_, n_] := Module[{data, h, w, nrows, ncols, i, j, tmp, new},
  data = ImageData[img, "Byte"];
  {h, w} = Most@Floor[Dimensions[data]/n];
  {nrows, ncols} = Most@Dimensions[data];
  {nrows, ncols} = {h Quotient[nrows, h], w Quotient[ncols, w]};
  data = Part[data, ;; nrows, ;; ncols];

  i = Rest@Most@Range[nrows + 2 nrows/h];
  i = Drop[i, {h + 1, UpTo[Infinity], h + 2}];
  i = Drop[i, {h + 1, UpTo[Infinity], h + 1}];

  j = Rest@Most@Range[ncols + 2 ncols/w];
  j = Drop[j, {w + 1, UpTo[Infinity], w + 2}];
  j = Drop[j, {w + 1, UpTo[Infinity], w + 1}];

  tmp = ConstantArray[Developer`ToPackedArray[{255, 255, 255}], {nrows + 2 nrows/h, ncols}];
  tmp[[i]] = data;

  new = ConstantArray[Developer`ToPackedArray[{255, 255, 255}], {nrows + 2 nrows/h, ncols + 2 ncols/w}];
  new[[All, j]] = tmp;

  Image[new, "Byte"]
 ]

showParts[img, 64] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The image data is never unpacked in this code.

To get the partitions, we can then apply OP's `splitImage` function, with good performance:

```
splitImage[showParts[img, 64], 64]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.019043, Null}`

(This will give us partitions that have been padded with a white border. It is unclear to me if this was desired on its own, or if those were only produced to be able to construct the image. In either case, here it is, if desired.)

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to first extract the [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html), [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) it, [`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad.html) with {1, 1, 1}, convert it to [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html), and finally use [`ImageAssemble`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAssemble.html).

```
arrPadImage = (ArrayPad[#, {{1}, {1}}, Hold[{1, 1, 1}]] // ReleaseHold // Image) &;
imagePartitionPad[img_, n_] := 
  Partition[ImageData[img], Floor@(ImageDimensions[img]/n)] // 
   ImageAssemble[Outer[arrPadImage, #, 2]] &;
```

For the given image, this method takes about `0.34 s` compared to yours which takes about `3.63 s`.

```
imagePartitionPad[imsq, 64]
```

> [image]

```
ImageData[imagePartitionPad[imsq, 64]] == ImageData[showParts[splitImage[imsq, 64]]]
```

> True

Comment: Please, what processor do you use?

Comment: I'm using Intel i7 7700 (Windows 10).

Answer (score 6):

This is almost the other answer, just slightly more vectorized and using integers for the data array which seems to be faster:

```
split[img_, n_] := Image[ArrayFlatten[ArrayPad[Partition[
      ImageData[img, "Byte"], Reverse[Floor[ImageDimensions[img]/n]]],
       {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{{{{255, 255, 255}}}}}]], "Byte"]

split[ImageAssemble[{{img, img}}], 64]
```

Edit: To extract parts:

```
Clear[split];
split[im_, n_] := Partition[ImageData[im, "Byte"], Reverse[Floor[ImageDimensions[im]/n]]]

show[parts_] := Image[ArrayFlatten[ArrayPad[parts, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}},
                                                   {{{{{255, 255, 255}}}}}]], "Byte"]

parts = split[ImageAssemble[{{img, img}}], 64];
subImages = Map[Image[#, "Byte"] &, parts, {2}];

show[parts]
```

Comment: A bit faster that the previous

Comment: @Coolwater  How can you access each individual part following your approach?

Comment: @Majis I think it depends on the purpose how that should be done, see edit

Comment: @Coolwater Thanks. While calculating `parts` you've used `img` twice (probably by mistake).

Comment: If you pack all your results you can go from ~.080s to ~.055s (i.e. toss ``Developer`ToPackedArray@`` in front of `Partition`, `ArrayPad`, and `ArrayFlatten`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a super naive (but nonetheless very fast) method for generating the padded image, not for splitting (since that problem is almost trivially handled via `Partition`) that preserves the `ImageColorSpace` and leverages the power of `PackedArray` by not padding with `1` but rather with `1.`:

```
splitty[img_, n_, padColor : {__?NumericQ} | _?NumericQ : 1] :=

  Module[
   {
    data = ImageData@img,
    dd,
    ins1,
    ins2,
    paddy
    },
   dd = Dimensions[data];
   paddy =
    N@
     Switch[padColor,
      _?NumericQ,
      ConstantArray[padColor, dd[[3]]],
      _,
      PadRight[padColor, dd[[3]], 1][[;; dd[[3]]]]
      ];
   ins1 =
    Insert[data, 
     paddy,
     Flatten[
      Table[
       {i, j},
       {i, 1, dd[[1]]},
       {j, 1, dd[[2]], Floor[dd[[1]]/n]}
       ],
      1
      ]
     ];
   ins2 =
    Insert[
     ins1,
     ConstantArray[paddy, Length@ins1[[1]]],
     List /@ Range[1, Length@ins1,  Floor[dd[[2]]/n]]
     ];
   Image[ins2,
    ColorSpace -> ImageColorSpace@img
    ]
   ];
```

Note that it performs surprisingly well:

```
splitty[img, 64] // RepeatedTiming // First

0.014

splitty[img, 64]
```

[image: asdasdas]

And you can insert an arbitrary color:

```
splitty[img, 100, .5]
```

[image: graygray]

```
splitty[img, 100, {.6, .6, 0}]
```

[image: wowwowowow]

Comment: so you worked directly on the original data,adding a constant array  in the right position. very clever and fast!

Comment: The real trick is actually that `N` call (basically using `1.` instead of `1`). This allows Mathematica to keep the data as a `PackedArray` as it maintains the type of the data (`Real` vs. `Integer`) on which vectorized operations can be applied incredibly fast.

Comment: do i get any advantage if i replace 1 with 1. inside hold or does it convert tthe machine precision number back to 1 ?

Comment: Not a major one, but like .04 seconds on a few tests I just ran. The problem is the `Hold`. `Hold` can't be interpreted as a numeric type and so Mathematica unpacks the array.

Answer (score 4):

```
table = Flatten@ImagePartition[image, ImageDimensions[image]/64]
ImageCollage[table, ImagePadding -> 1, Background -> White, 
 Method -> "Grid"]
```

gives:

[image]

**Update**: as Josè noted, my answer, though formally correct, is slower than the original and should not be considered.

**New Solution:**

```
data= ImageData[image];
zn = Image@
   ReleaseHold@
    ArrayFlatten@
     BlockMap[ArrayPad[#, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, Hold[{1., 1., 1.}]] &, data, 
      Floor[Dimensions[data]/64][[1 ;; 2]]] // RepeatedTiming
```

while the first answer took almost 17 seconds to show the result, the new one, on the same laptop, ends in just

> 0.076s

Comment: Please check, it is slower...

Comment: As I noted to Coolwater, you can (almost certainly) get a speed boost by packing your arrays. I haven't tested it in your case, but since your and Coolwater's solutions are essentially the same my assumption is the speed boost will still apply.

Comment: uhm i tried adding `Developer`ToPackedArray@`  but the timing doesn't change much ( more or less 1 millisecond)

Comment: @Alucard where'd you add it? The `BlockMap` might change the efficiency. Also your solution isn't entirely robust. First off your `Imagedata` isn't correct and also when it works on an image with an alpha channel it fails.

Comment: @b3m2a1 i added it near `ArrayPad` . i can fix easily  `ImageData`  but , in the case of images with an Alphachannel ,replacing `Hold[{1,1,1}]`  with a 4-dimensional vector  change the original colors

Comment: Of course. Just good to keep in mind that you need that check. I realized the reason ``Developer`ToPackedArray`` can't really help you is your don't have numerical data so you can get the benefits of packing. `Hold` makes it fail.

Comment: yes, i initially tried to use ArrayPad  without using `Hold`  but it  failed to give the desired result, Kumar's answer helped me a lot